# ValueError: Input 8 of layer sequential 11 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Trying to build a NNet for regression task. But while doing that, I'm getting some dimension related or size related error thrown. Can someone please have a look?

```py
numeric features = df_lagged_fs.select_dtypes (include="number").columns

numeric_features = [word for word in numeric_features if word != "atm_withdrawals.total_amount"] 

categorical_features = df_lagged_fs.select_dtypes (exclude="number").columns
```

```py
numeric_transformer = Pipeline (steps-[('scaler', StandardScaler())]) 
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder (handle_unknown="igmnore"))])

preprocesssor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features)
, ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical features)
])
```

```py
model tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense (64, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)) 
, tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')
, tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])

 pipeline = Pipeline (steps=[ =
('preprocessor', preprocesssor)
, ('model', model)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='huber_loss")
```

```py
history = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train, model__epochs=20, model__verbose=2)
```

When running this, I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Input 8 of layer sequential 11 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have va lue 17 but received input with shape (None, 186)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you print your data shape (X_train, y_train) and the model summary?